# New line in output file / unix , sql script

Tags: sql, linux, unix, sqlplus

As I'm unix newbie, I have to ask you for a help. 
I'm trying to execute SQL script by using sqlplus. 
It works fine but the problem is output file,

I'm using

```
sqlplus -s /nolog @scriptname.sql filename.txt
```

Sql script contain one record where columns are concatenating, just like:

```
select abc||''||def||chr(9)||''||ghi||''||'064' , as separator I'm using tab (char(9)).
```

The problem is that output file looks:

```
abc def    ghi
064
```

It should be

```
abc def    ghi 064
```

New line is unnecessary, I tried to add into my unix script:

```
set pagesize 0;
set pagesize none;
```

Unfornately it doesn't work, any ideas? 
Thanks m

Comment: does your script set linesize?

Comment: No, only one is set pagesize 0;

Comment: Omg... You are right, I set linesize on 32k. Now it works. That's why I'm newbie and you are expert. Thanks :)

Comment: not an expert by any means. just learning like you :)